# Unable to SSH to F5 Load Balancer(BIGIP) using Perl

Tags: perl, ssh, f5, big-ip

I am trying to connect to F5 load balancer through perl module Net::SSH2. SSH2 "connect" method is working but I am unable to authenticate, whereas with the same credentials I am able to ssh to the device through putty. I have shared the Code and the error below for reference. Can somebody please help me with this.

***Error***

> Authentication failed (username/password) (-18
>   LIBSSH2_ERROR_PUBLICKEY_UNRECOGNIZED) at test.pl line 8. successfully
>   connected

***Code***

```
use strict;
use Net::SSH2;

my $ssh=Net::SSH2->new();

if($ssh->connect('xx.xx.xx.xx'))
  {
     print "successfully connected";
  }

$ssh->auth_password('username','password') or $ssh->die_with_error;
```

Can somebody please help.

Comment: Maybe the remote host requires `password-interactive` authentication. Instead of calling `auth_password` use `auth`: `$ssh->auth(username => $username, password => $password)`

Comment: thanks a lot buddy. it worked like a charm :)